# ondragover, ondragstart and ondrop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

The `ondragover="functioname(event)`, `ondragstart="functioname(event)` and `ondrop="functioname(event)` are used inside HTML tags. I want to separate JS from HTML, but I can't find how to do so and if there will be some performance impact(I want to use native HTML5 drag'n'drop).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your element and then try to retrieve them using that id and then add event listeners to them.

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.ondragover = functionname;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to handle events in web pages. 
- Using attributes like you has shown
- Using js objects and methods

You want the second options, aren't you?

You may try to write your own code (see api descriptions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) or use third-party libs for that purpose (https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula, http://interactjs.io/, so on).